# How to link a custom menu to a custom button in drupalgap?

Tags: javascript

I would like to put the pop-up main_menu written in the `setting.js` to my custom button. It seems that the path name I use is not correct.

`l('Menu', 'main_menu', { attributes: { 'data-icon': 'star' } })`

I also tried this and does not successful. The second parameter in `l( )` link path is needed.

`l('Menu', { attributes: { 'data-icon': 'star' }, popup: true, popup_delta: 'main_menu' })`

So, what is the correct path name of the main_menu? or how do I link my custom menu to my custom button or link?

This is how I do my custom popup button:

`var btn_setup = theme('popup', {
            content: theme('jqm_item_list', {
                items: [
                  l('View profile', 'user'),
                  l('Login', 'user/login'),
                  l('Logout', 'user/logout')
                ]
            }),
            button_text: 'Setup',
            button_attributes: {
              'data-icon': 'gear'
            }
        });`

It does not popup anthing, even I just put a simple content, such as:

`content:'<p>This is a test</p>'`

nothing happen when clicking the button.

After several experiments, the popup function needs to set the page id.

`var btn_setup = theme('popup', {
            content: theme('jqm_item_list', {
                items: [
                  l('View profile', 'user'),
                  l('Login', 'user/login'),
                  l('Logout', 'user/logout')
                ]
            }),
            attributes: {
              id: drupalgap_get_page_id() + '_this_page_hook'
            },
            button_text: 'Setup',
            button_attributes: {
              'data-icon': 'gear'
            }
        });`

So the question is, when I put this button in the header or footer, I want it display in any page. How do I set the page id for any page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When put in the header or footer block, just give the page id the block name. Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function footer_intrfc_block_info() {
  var blocks = {};
  blocks['footer_intrfc_block'] = {
    delta: 'footer_intrfc_block',
    module: 'footer_intrfc'
  };
  return blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function footer_intrfc_block_view(delta, region) {

var html = '<div>';
var btn_setup = theme('popup', {
            content: theme('jqm_item_list', {
                items: [
                  l('View profile', 'user'),
                  l('Login', 'user/login'),
                  l('Logout', 'user/logout')
                ]
            }),
            attributes: {
               id: drupalgap_get_page_id() + '_footer_intrfc_block'
            },
            button_text: 'Setup',
            button_attributes: {
              'data-icon': 'gear'
            }
        });
html += btn_setup + '</div>';
return html
}
```